# RxJS - Unit testing mergeMap inner Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
  createAsset(asset: Asset): void {
    this._assetsService.uploadFile()
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(_ => this._assetsService.createAsset({
        ...asset,
        extension: 'png'
      })),
      take(1)
    )
    .subscribe(_ => {}, _ => console.error(_));
  }
```

And I would like to ensure that whenever this function is called, and it calls `createAsset` with the right parameters.

I did write a UT using `Karma` and `Jasmine`:

```
it('...', async (async () => {
    const assetsService = TestBed.inject(AssetsService);
    const uploadSpy = spyOn(assetsService, 'uploadFile').and.returnValue(of());
    const createSpy = spyOn(assetsService, 'createAsset').and.returnValue(of());

    const extension = 'png';

    const asset = {
      name: 'name',
      extension: null
    };

    component.createAsset(asset);

    await fixture.whenStable();
    expect(uploadSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(createSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({...asset, extension}); // Error : This is never called
  }));
```

The inner obversable from the `mergeMap` `createSpy` is never called.
Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Maybe this is because of equality check by reference instead of value, could you see if `createSpy` was called with any parameters at all?

Comment: Your test seems to work in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unit-tests-d9gcp1?file=src%2Ftesting%2Fsome.component.spec.ts), could you please reproduce the error?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this test and its assertions work as expected. If it's a simpler version of original issue - please share the original one then.

Comment: It's actually not a simpler version, I am on Jasmine 3.5.0 and Karma 4.4.1

Comment: you miss something that's a 1:1 copy of your test: http://mono.olovei.com/screencast%202020-05-26%2012-14-42.mp4

Comment: The issue was coming from the Observable<void> using the returnValue. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const uploadSpy = spyOn(assetsService, 'uploadFile').and.returnValue(of());
```

the issue lies in the mock using a `Observable<void>` simply replacing it by anything other than `void` fixed the issue.